# Rstudio: use .N in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I created a small test dataframe. I want to fill a new column var3 with values. If in the corresponding row var2 = A, the number of A-values from column var2 should be specified. If the corresponding row var2 = B, the number of B values from column var2 is to be specified.

I imagine something like this:

```
var1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
var2 <- c("A","B","B","B","A")
df <- data.frame(var1,var2)

df$var3 <- 0
N_var3 <- df[.N, by = df$var2]

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$var2 == "A") {
    df$var3[i] <- N_var3[1]
  }  else {
    df$var3[i] <-N_var3[2] 
  }
}
```

the result should be:

```
df$var3 <- c(2,3,3,3,2)
```

is there another way without having to use a loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many variables you may have in `var2`?

Comment: in this example 2, in others up to 15

Comment: I think you just want `df %>% add_count(var2)`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento That's the best approach, totally forgot this function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be a general approach regardless of the number of variables in your `var2` column:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(var3 = sum(.$var2 == var2))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Rowwise: 
   var1 var2   var3
  <dbl> <chr> <int>
1     1 A         2
2     2 B         3
3     3 B         3
4     4 B         3
5     5 A         2
```

Comment: You're welcome, In case there is a need for further modifications just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`df %>% add_count(var2)` is the easiest way.

I have to make another modification. I want to plot the df later and distinguish by color between two categories, which I add to the df with var4

```
var4 <- c("blue", "red", "red", "blue","blue")
```

If I now create a diagram, of course, no differences between "blue" and "red" show up, since these categories are not taken into account. Can I somehow include this modification?

Comment: For the purpose of distinction between the two categories coerce `var2` to `factor` with `factor` function and in case you are using `ggplot2` you can map it to `group` or  `color` aesthetics.